# Application development on meteor

Tags: meteor, web, intellij-idea

I am working on a project in my office, for this i have downloaded meteor project code from github for customization, i don't know how it's run before? i have successfully developed demo app from meteor tutorial, but when i am trying that unzipped github code and using same command in terminal as for demo app, its giving me an error "project not in meteor directory". But when i am using intellij idea for importing that, so .meteor directory is automatically getting created there.

What should i do for this. Please help i am in trouble.

Comment: do you have a `.meteor` directory in the root directory of your project?

Comment: No, On windows i can see meteor directory in my project folder, but on mac .meteor folder is invisible. On mac when using intellj idea to .meteor directory is visible.

Comment: It does not matter whether it is "hidden" (as a dot dir it is "hidden" by convention"), just that it exists and that it includes some required files, such as `.id` and `packages`. Does it? I would `git clone` the project directly from GitHub instead of getting an archive, as then you would be able to easily commit your changes to the repo. Run the `meteor` command from the root directory of your project. If it does not work, I would consult the programmers who created the original application.

Comment: i found something, in intellij idea i am using github option from "check out from version control" and cloning of that directory happens there, now intellij idea asking me - would you like to create an IDEA project for this source you have checked out to /users/username/myappname ?

What should i choose YES or NO ?

Comment: First things first. Clone the repo and run `meteor` from the root project dir (using the terminal, not Idea) and see what that gives you. I don't normally create projects like this in Idea, so I wouldn't know what to answer. You can probably safely let it create a project, as long as you don't commit the `.idea` directory if you don't want the project metadata in your repo.

Comment: i have follow the step.
1. cloning project from github through terminal, in /users/username/ directory.
2. Through terminal i am using /users/username/app_name/
3. getting output app_name git:(master)

Comment: and i have tried there to run command in app_name git:(master), the command for add platform and created there environment variables and then tried to run that aap so getting issue, not in meteor project. my .meteor directory is inside /appname/code/.meteor i saw this on github. what should i do, how it will run?

Comment: so run the `meteor` command from the `code` directory. The project's root directory is the directory that contains the `.meteor` directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your command line is not projected in your meteor project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would solve your problem

Step 1. Create a meteor app with "meteor create appName"

Step 2. Delete all the files from the app you created in previous step.

Step 3. Unzip and save all the files in appName directory which is created while doing the first step.

Let me know if there is error again.

Comment: Can i use intellij idea to run that aap?

Comment: yes you can though I havent used it but my friends do and they find it good!

Answer (score 0):

Meteor Upadated tutorials with react js are explained our blog [Meteor Js For React Developers](https://aboosbox.wordpress.com/2016/12/14/meteor-1-4-with-react-for-beginners/)